# How to make an app in script editor that executes a javascript and also a shell script?

Tags: javascript, macos

I have an app that is compiled in automator for `MacOS`.
it executes a javascript and then shell script. It is a bit slow though to execute and i noticed that apps compiled in script editor instead are faster to execute. how do i make an app in script that executes this javascript and shell script ?

```js
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript
function run(input) {
    const app = Application.currentApplication();
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

    const obsidianJsonFilePath = app.pathTo("home folder") + "/Library/Application Support/obsidian/obsidian.json";
    const vaults = JSON.parse(app.read(obsidianJsonFilePath)).vaults;

    let openInObsi = false;
    const pathArray = input.toString().split(",");
    const toOpen = [];
    pathArray.forEach(filePath => {
        const isFileInObsidianVault = Object.values(vaults).some(v => filePath.startsWith(v.path));
        if (isFileInObsidianVault && !filePath.includes("/.")) { // second condition prevents the opening of files in .obsidian or .trash
            toOpen.push("obsidian://open?path=" + encodeURIComponent(filePath));
            openInObsi = true;
        }
        else toOpen.push(filePath);
    });
    return [openInObsi.toString(), ...toOpen];

}
```

Shell Script

```bash
if $1 ; then
    open "$2"
else
    open -a "Obsidian" "${@:2}"
fi
```

Didn't tried anything, because I am not familiar with this code.

Comment: There's definitely nothing _wrong_ with using the JS interpreter built-in to macOS, but you might find it easier to use another JS runtime which includes more system API bindings that will make it easy to do everything in your JavaScript code instead of in separate languages (e.g. [Deno](https://deno.land/), [Node](https://nodejs.org/)).

Comment: Thank you for that but do you know how to make the above into an app in script editor? Or maybe step by step instructions on how to compile it in deno/node? Cheers